# WPF MenuItem Hover Style padding Issue

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm beginner in WPF. So please I need to understand what is going on with those gaps between the border and the contents. I'm having this issue also in **Buttons** as well.

In short, I've a style for MenuItem as shown below, The problem is when I Hover the Item and move the pointer between the MenuItem edge and the content, the border will disappear . I think there is something wrong with padding or margins.

I want the border to be visible always when the pointer is inside the Item.

```
<Style TargetType="MenuItem" x:Key="MenuItemsStyle">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3,0,3,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Border Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                        x:Name="B1"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ContentPresenter
                            x:Name="Textb"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                            ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}"
                            ContentSource="Header"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                            TextElement.Foreground="Black">
                            <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Border>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Property=Content}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="B1" Value="Gray"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>

        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `Background` property of your outermost `Border`.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Border Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
            x:Name="B1"
            Background="Transparent"
            ...
    </Border>
    ...
</ControlTemplate>
```